# Unable to locate <a> element using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm a newbie with Selenium trying a project out and I'm trying to click on a link on a page but Selenium says it could not find the element. Here is the inspected element:

```
<a data-action="renditions--schedule-item-list#showAvailableItems" class="available-items-btn">
        <i class="icon-bullhorn"></i>
        Available Items
</a>
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[text()="Available Items"]').click()
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("a.available-items-btn").click()
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: are you sure the element is loaded? Have you tried using a wait (or a sleep)?

Comment: @DMart Ah, such a silly error. The element I was looking for didn't load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes finding by exact text match doesn't always work.  Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Available Items')]")
```

Or, try your second attempt again but remove the `a.`

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("available-items-btn").click()
```

Comment: I tried both of them but they didn't work. I also copied the full xpath using the Chrome inspector but that didn't work either. Not sure what the problem is.